# Python 3.4.3 program does not work outside the IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner and wrote the following in Python 3.4.3 using Wing IDE 1.0.1

```
sidea = float( input ( " eerste rechtshoekzijde:") )
sideb= float ( input ( "tweede rechtshoekzijde:") )
tussenstap= sidea *sidea + sideb * sideb
print( int( tussenstap))
sidec= int( tussenstap **0.5)
print("de lengte van de lange zijde is", sidec)
```

In the IDE environment it works just fine. But when I double click on the program after saving it does not work. I can enter variable 1 and variable 2, but when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it shows the answer in a split second and the screen disappears.

It is configured well, so there is no problem with version 2 on one hand en 3 on the other hand. Can someone please help me?

Comment: you are missing a 't' in the last print... should be working that aside.

Comment: no the t is wrong here, but in the program it is there, so that aint the problem thx.

Comment: @thales78 If the last line is `print("de lengte van de lange zijde is", sidec)` in your program, you should edit the question and add it there, too. Otherwise everybody will think that this was the mistake.

Comment: @thales78 Are you using Windows?

Comment: yes i am using windowd, and yes you are right about that t.

Answer (score 2):

> it shows the answer in a split second and the screen disappears.

That’s because when you double-click the `.py` file in Windows, a new console application running your Python script is launched. And that console application terminates as soon as your script is done doing whatever it does.

So in your case, it asks for input, and then prints something; and then it’s done doing things. So the Python process terminates and the window disappears.

A very common solution to this “problem” is to ask for some final input at the end of your script:

```
print("de lengte van de lange zijde is", sidec)

input('Press enter to quit this application')
```

So now, we’re just asking the user to press enter, and only *then* the script is done doing things and the window may disappear.

Another solution would be to simply launch your script inside an existing console application, so that when the Python process terminates, the window returns to your console instead of closing itself. To do this, launch the Windows command line, e.g. by starting `cmd` from the Run-window (<kbd>WinKey + R</kbd>), and then typing `python myscript.py`. This will launch the `myscript.py` in the current directory, without terminating the console process after the script finishes.

Comment: Thx thx thx, this makes sense to me. So this 'problem' is normal. and i understand why. thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, it’s absolutely normal, and a very common issue when beginners start with console applications (not only in Python but in every programming language).

Comment: Well i guess it is, but i dont understand why the tutorial does not mention this. perhaps it will later on. :-)

Comment: The tutorial expects you to run your scripts from an existing command line, as that’s the common way across different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a console and run the program with the following command:

python

By doing that the console won't close right after the program finishes

Comment: I am really new at this, how do i open a console? please tell me step by step

Comment: Well, it depends on the operating system you are using.

For example if you're using windows you can search for the command line . It will open a console, then the simplest way is to use chdir to the path where your script is located and then just use the above command

Comment: another solution, although kind of cheesy is to add a line of code that waits for input from the user to the end of the script:  `input()`

Comment: I am using windows 8 , remember i am really new. i dont know the terminologie, what is a consol, what is a command line?

Comment: The solution of abd Azrad does work, but still i wonder, why the problem is there in the first place? what is the problem? i have a chessy solution that works, thx for that abd azrad, but still what is the problem in the first place?

Comment: Well I guess it will be easier to follow the suggestion of @AbdAzrad and add a input() line at the end of the code. This will allow you to see the output until enter is pressed.

Comment: The problem is, your script does what it was told to do, and when it is finished it is closing the window. However, you are human being and read slowly so you can't read the output before it finishes and closes. The input() trick keeps it open because it can't finish until you type something. You should learn to open and use the command line though, so start googling!

Comment: Thx Abd AZRad, your suggestion was helpfull, but start googling is not really an awnser is it? Since google brought me here in the first place. but still thx for you awnser. I dont know what you mean by command line, so i will start googling again.

Comment: You could try opening a new question about the command line with a windows-8 tag, sorry I don't know windows very well.

Comment: I will  later on, but for know this problem is 'solved'thx too you and all.